# How to get a list of all tables and views that uses a view?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a view in Postgresql that I need to change.
Before I change it I need to know who uses it.

I found out easily which functions uses it.. but I'm having trouble find out which views/tables uses it.

I wrote this code:

```
SELECT classid::regclass,*
FROM pg_depend
WHERE refobjid = 'customerview'::regclass
```

this gives me many ids but no tables\views name.

How can I get the names?

Comment: Don't worry [a-horse-with-no-name](http://stackoverflow.com/users/330315/a-horse-with-no-name) is online ;P

Comment: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Pg_depend_display

Comment: What exaxly I'm looking at there?

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you?

```
SELECT  DISTINCT dependee.relname
FROM    pg_depend 
        JOIN pg_rewrite             ON pg_depend.objid = pg_rewrite.oid 
        JOIN pg_class AS dependee   ON pg_rewrite.ev_class = dependee.oid 
        JOIN pg_class AS dependent  ON pg_depend.refobjid = dependent.oid 
        JOIN pg_attribute           ON pg_depend.refobjid = pg_attribute.attrelid 
                                    AND pg_depend.refobjsubid = pg_attribute.attnum 
WHERE   dependent.relname = 'Your_TableOrViewName_Here'
        AND pg_attribute.attnum > 0;
```